# Editing existing SSRS report - issue with formatting

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I've been editing/creating SSRS report for a bit sometime now but today I came across something that I'm really not sure about.

The report has a Tablix with about 8 columns. I needed to add an additional column in between some of the columns. However, i'm not able to format it (vertical align) as the other ones are formatted. If I try to change the formatting of the header of existing fields from Default to Middle it simply does not do anything. Also, I noticed that if I right click on one of the already existing headers in the tablix, the Expression is greyed out, basically not able to select it (as shown below)
[image]

In this case DOB is an already existing field, so right clicking on it prevents me from choosing Expression. Also, as the textbox in pic shows, both have the Vertical Align set to DEFAULT yet "Blah" looks out of place. Changing vertical align of DOB does not move it at all. It seems locked in place is there such a thing?

[image]

Comment: are there any carriage returns / line feeds in "Blah"?

Comment: That's very weird, try selecting the whole row and change the verticalAlign.

Comment: No well the thing was I simply dragged the field from my dataset into the tablix and then updated the heading text to BLAH (using as example). Please see edit another interesting thing I noticed @Jayvee

Comment: @JanuaryMmako it seems like only BLAH cell was formatted to middle - nothing else

Comment: @Jayvee - what I'm showing in my 2nd image is that BLAH has an extra field on the right VALUE: under which is says BLAH. While DOB does not, it only shows Name and ToolTip? why is that i wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are blank lines (cr/lf) in "DOB" and/or "Blah". Double click on the cell and make sure to remove the extra lines. 
This should make "expression" to show in the drop down and also responsive to alignment.